# Let $a,b\in\mathbb N$ be sides of a rectangle and the area, $A=4\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+4(a+b)$. Find $a$ and $b$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $a,b\in\mathbb N$ be sides of a rectangle and the area, $A=4\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+4(a+b)$. Find $a$ and $b$.

This problem was in my number theory exam but I am not sure if my proof is correct. Any comment will help. Here is my proof.

We know that the area of a rectangle is $ab$. So, $ab=4\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+4(a+b) \Rightarrow$
$ab-4(a+b)=4\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. Here it's obvious that $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ is also a natural number. Squaring both sides we get:

$$a^2b^2+16(a+b)^2-8ab(a+b)=16\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\Rightarrow
a^2b^2+32ab-8ab(a+b)=0\\ \Rightarrow ab(ab+32-8(a+b))=0$$

($ab\neq0$), so $ab+32-8(a+b)=0$. Finally, we get that $a={8(b-4)\over b-8}$.

We know that a is a natural number so $8(b-4)\equiv 0 \bmod(b-8)\Rightarrow 8b\equiv32 \bmod(b-3)$. Adding to the left side $-8(b-8)\equiv0 \bmod(b-8)$. We get, $8b-8(b-8)\equiv32 \bmod(b-8)\Rightarrow 64\equiv32$ $\bmod(b-8)\Rightarrow 32\equiv0 \bmod(b-8)$ in other words $(b-8)\mid 32$ the possible solutions for these are: $(b-8)=1,2,4,8,16,32$ or $b=9,10,12,16,24,40$.

So we have the solutions $(a,b)=(40,9),(24,10),(16,12),(12,16),(10,24),(9,40)$.

I wonder if there are any other solutions.
Any help/addition will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to be careful with this: You concluded from $(b-8)\mid 32$ that $b-8 = 1,2,4,8,16, 32$, but the divisors of $32$ are $\pm 1,\pm  2,\pm  4,\pm  8,\pm 16,\pm  32$. So it could be, for example, that $b-8 = -2$, so $b=6$. This time you were lucky because $b=6$ gives a negative value for $a$, so we can discard it, but the negative divisors should always be considered because in other situations negative divisors could lead to positive solutions.

Comment: You can avoid the congruence calculations with simple polynomial division: $a=\frac{8(b-4)}{b-8} = 8 + \frac{32}{b-8}$, so $b-8 \mid 32$.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a short solution , this an idea: Suppose a and be make a Pythagorian triple such that:

$$a^2+b^2=c^2\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space(1)$$

So we have:

$$A=a\cdot b=4(a+b+c)$$

This is the restriction. We may write:

$$2ab=8(a+b+c)\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space(2)$$

summing with (1) we get:

$$(a+b)^2=8(a+b)+8c+c^2$$

Solving for $(a+b)$ we have:

$$\Delta'=16+8c+c^2$$

This is perfect square for some C:

$c=16 \rightarrow a+b=28\rightarrow a=16, b=12$

$c=24 \rightarrow a+b=34\rightarrow a=24, b=10$

$c=41 \rightarrow a+b=49\rightarrow a=40, b=9$

You can continue and find more solutions for a and b.